# Unable to clear cookie in IE11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, cookies, session-cookies

I managing a session based on a cookie, which I am deleting on some user event. After that I reload the page. Rest of the browsers are redirected to the login page except IE11(it simply reloads the current page).
Following is the code I am using:

```
function logout() {
    document.cookie = 'SESSIONCOOKIE=;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;';
    setTimeout(function() {
        window.location = getCurrentUrl();
    }, 50);
}
```

But the next time user tries to logout, even IE also logs out.  Is there a way I can logout in IE in the first go?